# Remove unused images from Javascript project

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

Is there any way (by javascript code or by VS code Extension) to remove unused images from javascript front end project made in Mithril?

My current architecture is as follows -

assets

- images
- css
- js
- fonts

I am using "roll up" as module bundler.

Currently project has many unreferenced/unused images and fonts, which I would want to remove. Pls let me know the way to do it either programatically or thru any extension

Comment: It's hard to say. If you're using a Webpack-based build process with the file loader, for example, any images not imported into some component will be tree-shaken out.

Comment: Please provide more details what you are currently using and what do you want to achieve.

Comment: I have done editing, please check.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem this morning, this VSCode extension solve it successfully.

Search extension named SuitUp - Assets Manager.

[image]

Comment: this extension has some issues, Chinese Character regular expressions can't be executed. Such as /^[^\u4e00-\u9fa5]+./g, some images named in Chinese characters also find out.